# traversing tables with selenium/webdriverjs

Tags: arrays, node.js, selenium, webdriver, ui-testing

I want to traverse table with Selenium using Node and webdriverJS:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Peter</td>
    <td class="count">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">John</td>
    <td class="count">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want for every row to look at the names and the rows cells.

What I have:

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName('tr')).then(function(rows){

    // for every row
    for (var i = 0; i< rows.length; i++){
        // check the name cell
        rows[i].findElement(By.class('name')).getInnerHtml().then(function(name){
            // do some stuff
        });

        // check the count cell
        rows[i].findElement(By.class('count')).getInnerHtml().then(function(count){
            // do some stuff
        });
    }

});
```

This works for the first some rows, but with many rows it fails at a certain point.

My theory: the `findElement` calls in the for-loop are passed to the manager, then the for-loop finishes. Then the garbage collector removes the rows array. Once the manager executes the the `findElement` calls, the array and its elements do not exist anymore and fail. The error I get is:

`StaleElementReferenceException : The Element is not Attached to the DOM`

It does work for the first row as the array still exists early-on in the execution.

My questions:

1. what am I doing wrong?
2. Is my theory correct?
3. How can I bind the `row[i]` references to the findElement calls for them to persist longer than the original array?

---- Edit ----

When I remove one of the inner findElement calls and only look for one cell per row, I am able to cover more rows. This made me think that, with this implementation, time plays a role. This should not be the case, so I am doing probably something wrong.

4. Is there anything like a `forEach` function in Selenium?

Comment: If you don't validate anything on the rows themselves, you could write an XPath for each cell type and iterate those individually to see if that works. Basically replace `driver.findElements(By.tagName('tr'))` with `driver.findElements(By.xpath('//tr/td[@class=\'name\']'))` and `driver.findElements(By.xpath('//tr/td[@class=\'count\']'))` respectively.

Comment: I was thinking of that option as well, but I want to keep the cells of a row together. In the end I want to associate the name and the count. That is why I wanted to go through it row by row and then going through the cells of a row.

Comment: If you replace your `// do some stuff` with something like `console.log(name)` and `console.log(count)` do you **still** get intermittent failures?

Comment: @pat Is the table dynamic in nature? Meaning does it get altered in any way at the time of looping through the rows. Also is there any kind of stack trace or further details on the stale element exception?

Comment: @Louis, there is actually some code there and it keeps failing.

Comment: @shri046 I am using Sencha Ext JS as a framework so it is a dynamic JS framework, however when the code is running I already made sure everything is loaded and there are no changes to the HTML anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

I am using a website implemented with Sencha EXTjs.

The table is created on top of a data store: Apparently, the store is called twice and the whole table is recreated in-between the calls.

So I somehow have to wait until the table has loaded for the second time...

This will be the next challenge.